# Great Delphi source code to read and learn from

Tags: delphi

This question relates to

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603/what-is-some-great-source-code-to-read

which compiles a list of great (in the sense of readable, elegant, ...) source code.

Part of the learning experience when reading source code is certainly independent of the language but every language has its own ways to do certain things. So in this question, I'm looking for great **Delphi** code.

What is some great Delphi source code to read and learn from? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My suggestions

- All the Jedi projects are very well written [JCL](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/index.php?title=JEDI_Code_Library) (Jedi code library), JVCL, JEDI Windows API Library (Great to learn abot windows api and header conversions).
- VCL and RTL Source code.
- [Virtual Tree View](http://www.delphi-gems.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=12&Itemid=38)

Comment: +1 Thanks! I have not looked at JCL/JVCL/JEDI yet, but I'll definitely put this on my list.

Answer (score 8):

The VCL/RTL itself is a very good example of great delphi code.  It is available at your delphi installation folder ($delphi)\source, except for the new Starter edition, which I heard does not include the source code.

Comment: Yes, except that you're reading component source instead of application source.

Comment: @Warren O.P. does not state application source at all, and not all source there is related to components (check the `DateUtils` unit for example)

Answer (score 5):

Well for once, if you ask me, the VCL is fairly well written, and you can learn quite a bit about the Windows API from it.

Then there is the much hyped [Delphi Web Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dws/), which sounds rather interesting.
I would also recommend [DEHL](http://alex.ciobanu.org/?page_id=162), which is quite a nice library, and the VirtualStringGrid, as a hugely popular and quite well written, though complex, component.

Then there is the JCL and JVCL, that I would also recommend.

Comment: For Delphi Web Script, there are also unit tests to come, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 3):

The [GExperts sourcecode on sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gexperts/).

Answer (score 2):

Obvious answer: My sources

- http://svn.berlios.de/viewvc/dzchart/utilities/Delphi7Help4Bds/trunk/
- http://svn.berlios.de/viewvc/dzchart/utilities/dzAutoSave/trunk/
- http://svn.berlios.de/viewvc/dzchart/utilities/dzCmdLineParser/trunk/
- http://svn.berlios.de/viewvc/dzchart/utilities/dzLib/trunk/
- http://svn.berlios.de/viewvc/dzchart/utilities/dzPrepBuild/trunk/

You saw that coming, didn't you?

Comment: I am the third then, I guess. :-)

Comment: I don't claim to be the best because everybody does that. So I am probably the worst.

Comment: @EdwinYip as I wrote: Everybody but me is the best. That makes me the worst.

Answer (score 2):

[Bold for Delphi](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/23890) - Framework, a masterpiece, huge and immaculately designed

[StarUML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/) - An UML Editor, wonderful clean design and code

[Clever Internet Suite](http://www.clevercomponents.com/products/inetsuite/index.asp) - Communication component set - clean architecture and code, commercial

Answer (score 1):

"*Good code*" is a rather subjective topic ... everyone has an opinion on what can be considered *good/bad code*.  Readable code might not necessarily be considered effective code, and vice-versa.

If your interest is learning how to create well-written code, you should instead *study any code* and find out how to improve or fix it.  When I was in the Air Force, part of the training I would give my new troops would include them visiting sites like [Koders](http://koders.com/info.aspx?page=LanguageReport&la=delphi) or [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/search/?q=delphi), where they would download source and analyze for functionality, effective results, coding standards, proper software engineering principles, etc.  They would look at the code and answer "*how would I do this differently*?"  This exercise gave them a much better understanding of what *well-written code* should look like.

My point is, you can't learn how to write "good code" if you don't know what "bad code" looks like.

Comment: Hmm.  Good code is maybe a loaded term.  "Idiomatic" might be a betterone. You need to read some VCL code, and other Delphi code that is idiomatic, so you can see the normal solutions.  For example,  Would you use TList<String>, TStringList, or Array of String? Well.  TStringList is the most common, the most ancient, and the most idiomatic.